# Get visibile text of UILabel with UIAutomation script

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Is there some way to get the truncate text with UIAutomation?

For example if I have a label with text = "Long text test" but it appears on runtime as "Long te...", I want to get "Long te..." value with UIAutomation.

Cheers!

Comment: Just curious why you would want that instead of the actual value

Comment: @Donovan just UX point of view. I want that the user see the complete text. If not, I am going to investigate with designer team. Just this :)